# What other coins have similar implementations of Kovri to hide IP addresses from the sender?

Tags: privacy, kovri

I just learned about Kovri and it seems to be a new trend for coins to hide the senders IP. What other similar implementations are there for other coins?

Answer (score 1):

The network layer is different from the blockchain layer. This feature is provided by the wallet, not consensus.

The Bitcoin Core wallet includes a mechanism to connect through Tor. Several other forks of Bitcoin offer this feature.

I2P is less-frequently used, since it requires more network participants to use the service. This was first used by Anoncoin.